# Accessing webservice in docker image from a macchine different from docker host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Good morning,
I'm a new user of docker technology and I'm facing some issue.
Any help will be appreciated (I update the question, thanks to the questions provided by @JRichardsz).

Here the problem:

- Docker Host: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. This is a VMWare virtual machine
- In the host no process is using port 80. (Running "sudo lsof -i :80" return no process name, if I do not start any docker image)
- if I stop the running docker image by "docker compose down", I have 2 network interfaces:

```
   docker0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
            inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
            ether 02:42:2f:a6:ae:d2  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

    ens160: flags=4163  mtu 1500
            inet 192.168.128.60  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.128.255
            inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fea6:60bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
            ether 00:50:56:a6:60:bb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 2929  bytes 251888 (251.8 KB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 424  bytes 53706 (53.7 KB)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

- when I start my docker image (this is a docker image provided by Xibo CMS developers), the network interfaces related to the docker image appears, and I'm able to view bridge information:

```
    bridge name         bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
    br-33e8e1916c0d     8000.024261f9ddaa       no              veth0b9040e
                                                                veth3c6ecf0
                                                                veth821b253
                                                                vethe879c11
    docker0             8000.02422fa6aed2       no
```

- when the docker is active, command "sudo lsof -i :80" provides me:

```
        COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
        docker-pr 25417 root    4u  IPv4 122292      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
        docker-pr 25423 root    4u  IPv6 122300      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

so web service inside docker image is active on all interfaces.

- If I open a browser inside the Linux docker Host, looking at url http://127.0.0.1/ I can access the web server page without any problem
- If I open a browser at  http://192.168.128.80/ in a PC connected in the same subnet of ens160,  I'm not able to reach the webserver.
- Please note, no firewall is active (if I shutdown docker image by "docker compose down" command, and try from a PC connected in the same subnet of ens160 to open a telnet connection to port 80 in 192.168.128.80, I can capture packets using tcpdump)
- After stopping the docker image, I performed the following commands on the docker host PC:

```
        

    sudo python3 -m http.server 80
```

connecting from a different PC using putty telnet on port 80, I can see messages on the python example command line (so no firewall issues)

Is there anyone that can help me find why the webservice inside docker image can be accessed only when opening webpage from Linux Docker Host machine?
Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: #1 Just to validate if it is related to docker, stop your container and start a simple process in port 80. Finally, In the another pc, try again http://192.168.128.80 . You could use a simple **python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80**   #2 Are your servers, virtual machines on windows ? #3 Try to test using telnet from the another pc

Comment: @JRichardsz thank you, I added the relevant information in my original question. I hope this is the right way to answer to your doubts. In any case:
+ I have a my host machine is a Linux VMware image
+ Running python example, confirms there is no issue related to firewal

Comment: Interesting... #1 Could you try with another image? Maybe it is a issue in your image. You could try with this [python image](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/547c09a43a3c61b82c2d385af1de0e7c#file-dockerfile) which returns "world" if your invoke http://127.0.0.1:port/hello #2 Could you share your docker run sentence?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried the image with another customer, and it works fine. 
I'm not the developer of this image, it is release by Xibo CMS community. The only difference of the two deploy (that uses the same Linux Host machine) seems related to the network. I suppose that the bridge interface assumes an IP address in conflict with the customer network setup.
On the Xibo forum, I found a similar issue. 

https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/docker-bridge-ip-conflict/18632

I will perform other tests, and I will provide required information.
Thank you once again